# MergeError: Incompatible merge dtype, dtype('O') and dtype('O'), both sides must have numeric dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I need to output a column that will indicate the time of the second event for each user (user_id). The column should be the same as the column 'second_event_time'. I have created a new DataFrame in which all the second events for each user are added. Then I added a column to the same DataFrame, where the time of the second event for each user was added. Then I sort them by the 'time' column and combine them using the merge_asof method. I get an error: MergeError: Incompatible merge dtype, dtype('O') and dtype('O'), both sides must have numeric dtype.
Can you tell me how to fix the error in my case?
It's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file_path')
sessions_start_user = data[data['events_ordinal_number'] == 2]
sessions_start_user['second_time'] = sessions_start_user['time']
data = data.sort_values('time')
sessions_start_user = sessions_start_user.sort_values('time')
data = pd.merge_asof(data,sessions_start_user[['time','user_id','second_time']],on='time',by='user_id')
```

This is a part of my original Data Frame (data)

```
    Unnamed: 0  time                user_id type        amount  target  feature1    feature2    events_ordinal_number   second_event_time   loan_ordinal_number events_time_diff    previous_loans_max_amount
0      0        2001-01-01 00:00:00 114     loanRequest 14651   NaN        1            1       1                       2001-01-25 05:00:00     1                   NaN              NaN
1      1        2001-01-01 01:00:00 199     loanRequest 13398   NaN        0            0       1                       2001-01-08 01:00:00     1                   NaN              NaN
2      2        2001-01-01 02:00:00 717     loanRequest 14525   NaN        0            0       1                       2001-01-09 16:00:00     1      .            NaN              NaN
3      3        2001-01-01 03:00:00 66      loan        14437   1.0        1            1       1                       2001-03-27 17:00:00     1                   NaN              NaN
4      4        2001-01-01 04:00:00 584     loanRequest 15861   NaN        1            0       1                       2001-01-05 10:00:00     1                   NaN              NaN
```

This is a part of the data display for one of the users, in the "events_ordinal_number" column the sequence numbers of all events for each of the users are indicated.

```
    Unnamed: 0  time                user_id type       amount   target  feature1    feature2    events_ordinal_number   second_event_time   loan_ordinal_number events_time_diff    previous_loans_max_amount
0   0           2001-01-01 00:00:00 114     loanRequest 14651   NaN        1            1           1                   2001-01-25 05:00:00    1                NaN                         NaN
581 581         2001-01-25 05:00:00 114     loanRequest 13611   NaN        1            0           2                   2001-01-25 05:00:00    1                24 days 05:00:00            NaN
624 624         2001-01-27 00:00:00 114     loanRequest 14515   NaN        1            0           3                   2001-01-25 05:00:00    1                1 days 19:00:00             NaN
```

I also used this, the indexes were adjusted to the correct order, but the error remained:

```
sessions_start_user=pd.concat([sessions_start_user, sessions_start_user.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)], axis=1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't provide images of data. Provide a minimal reproducible example (as **text**) instead.

Comment: @mozway Hello, I fixed it.

Comment: What are the dtypes of your columns? (especially `time` column)

Comment: @ozacha The "time" and 'second_time' columns have the type - str, the "user_id" column has the type -int64, in both DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the `time` column to a datetime first – `pd.merge_asof` does not work with string columns. From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

> on: Field name to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames. The data MUST be ordered. Furthermore this must be a numeric column, such as datetimelike, integer, or float.

Adding

```py
data["time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["time"])
```

to the beginning of your script should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, everything worked! Now all the data has appeared in the "second_time" column, but in the lines where "events_ordinal_number" == 1, there are NaN in the "second_time" column. Do you know what the reason might be?

Comment: `merge_asof` looks for a nearest match on the `on` column, by default looking backwards. As there are no records in `sessions_start_user` with `time` values _before_ the time of the first event, the `second_time` value is missing. 
Do you perhaps want to use a simple exact `pd.merge` instead?